# align histogram and scatter plot in R

Tags: r, alignment, background-image, histogram, scatter-plot

I am trying to show two plots, one histogram and one scatter plot, and I wanted them to be aligned with respect to x-axis. I have created my histogram with hist() and my scatter plot with ggplot2. However, I found problems to create a multiplot mixing these two, so I decided to create the histogram with ggplot2. Please, find below the codes:

```
loadedimage <- readTIFF("my_data05.tiff")
rasterizedimage <- rasterGrob(loadedimage, interpolate = TRUE)
realmadrid_colors <-c("#00529f", "#8cc1f3", "blue")
data_test <- subset(full_data, Rival == "Barcelona")
data_kroos <- subset(data_test, Jugador == "Kroos")

myscatter <- ggplot(data_kroos, aes(x = x1, y = y1)) + 
  annotation_custom(rasterizedimage, xmin = 0, xmax = 713, ymin = 0 , ymax = 497) +
  geom_point(aes(fill = factor(data_kroos$Resultado)),
         shape = 21, 
         size = 5) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=realmadrid_colors) + 
  guides(fill=guide_legend(title=NULL)) +
  coord_fixed() + 
  theme_bw() + 
  theme_no_axes(base.theme = theme_bw()) + 
  theme(legend.position = c(0.5, 0.04),
    legend.box = "horizontal",
    legend.direction = "horizontal",
    legend.box.background = element_rect(fill = NA, colour = "transparent"),
    legend.text = element_text(family = "Courier", size = 14),
    axis.title = element_blank(),
    axis.text = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks = element_blank(),
    plot.margin=unit(c(-0.05,-0.05,-0.05,-0.1),"in")
    )

myhistogram <- qplot(data_barca[data_barca$Sección == "Passes_All",]$x1, breaks=seq(0, 660, by = 66), alpha = 0.5, geom = "histogram")
```

If I try using grid.newpage() and grid.draw(), I get an error message: ncol(x) == ncol(y) is not TRUE

```
grid.newpage()
grid.draw(rbind(ggplotGrob(myscatter), ggplotGrob(myhistogram), size = "first"))
```

I want to get something like in http://biokit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/auto_examples/plot_scatter.html
(indeed I am still in the first step, my target is to exactly as in the former link), or something like [combine histogram with scatter plot in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35412297/combine-histogram-with-scatter-plot-in-r), but in that case it is not used ggplot2, and I am not sure if I can play around like using that package.

Any help is welcome! If you need me to upload any file, please, let me know.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You'll find the solution in [stackoverflow: ggplot2 - multiple plots scaling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42220917/ggplot2-multiple-plots-scaling)

Comment: Thank you! Finally the answer was using ggExtra:: ggMarginal. It was exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

A further search maybe is the answer for me! The word I was looking for is marginal histograms!

[Scatterplot with marginal histograms in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8545035/scatterplot-with-marginal-histograms-in-ggplot2?rq=1)